# SqlDependancy does not work

Tags: .net

I am trying to create a SQLDependency for enterprise library, there is something strange that onChange event never fired.

 
 
For SQLServer2005: 
Service Broker is enabled. 
CLR integration is enabled.

The query is a simple select statement on user defined table, the query is wrapped in sproc.

I have been told that I should find the notification status in sys.transmission_queue table, but it is empty, it seems that no notifications were made.

What is chances?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work when you use a query that selects from a user-created table?

Comment: Sorry obviously I am not clear, I edit the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *` is not allowed change it to `SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM sys.transmission_queue

This is not the query for notification, sys.transmission_queue is where I should find the notification message status "I have been told this"